# divisibility of polynomials and determinant relations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $f(x), g(x) \in A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Write $f(x)=\sum \alpha_{\omega} x^{\omega}, g(x) = \sum \beta_{\omega} x^{\omega}$ where $\omega = (\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n)$ with $\omega_i$ non-negative integers such that $\omega_1+\cdots+\omega_n = n$ and $x^{\omega}$ stands for the monomial $x_1^{\omega_1} \cdots x_n^{\omega_n}$ and $\alpha_{\omega}$ is the corresponding coefficient. Is it true that $f(x),g(x)$ are proportional, i.e. $f(x)$ is a multiple of $g(x)$ in the ring $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, if and only if all determinants $\alpha_{\omega} \beta_{{\omega}'} - \alpha_{{\omega}'} \beta_{\omega}=0, \, \, \, \forall \omega, \omega'?$ Any sketch for a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hypotheses, $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous of degree $n$. It follows that $f$ is a multiple of $g$ in the ring if and only if it is a multiple by a nonzero constant $a$ in $A$. This is easily seen to be equivalent to the condition on determinants.